# How to solve this message "repetition-operator operand invalid" of grep?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to extract texts by using grep on mac

used regex is like this

$grep -E '.+output:([\S\s](?!DEBUG))*?123456789[\S\s]*?END\]' ./AppLog.txt

"123456789" is search id.


then execute this regex,

terminal says "grep: repetition-operator operand invalid."

but In sublime text editor, it executes correctly.


How to fix this error of terminal on mac?

search text example)

I'd like to capture from "output" line to "END" line by UserID.



DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|blabla~~|output:

[START]

=========================================================

00 G_messageText             = {"success"}

01 NEW_CS_YN                 = {"N"}

02 G_messageID               = {"0006"}

03 sTaxYn                    = {"0"}

04 ErrorMsg                  = {"SUCC"}

05 ErrorCode                 = {"0"}

06 UserNum                   = {"111111111"}

07 UserID                    = {"123456789"}  <= search id

08 G_messageTitle            = {"notice"}

09 G_messageSeverity         = {"2"}

===============================================

[ END ]

DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|blabla~~~

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using "pcregrep".
you can install this program by typing 'brew install pcre'.

thanks.